# How to make a transaction in asp.net-core 2.0?

Tags: transactions, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to update some values but in case one fails I need to rollback. How can I do this in asp.net-core-2.0?

I have not found any answers yet. Is this because it is not yet supported? In that case what are some alternatives?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions

Comment: Thanks I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes man, using System.Transactions.TransactionScope, available since .Net Core 2.0 and above. check this:

Using System.Transactions in ASP.NET:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms229977

Implementing an Implicit Transaction using Transaction Scope:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms172152

Comment: As a improvement, you should quote the material relevant to this answer.  Links break and the answer becomes worthless later even if the linked material answered the question initially. At least if you include a summary, the answer can somewhat stand on its own

Answer (score 3):

```
//--INSIDE YOUR SAVE METHOD--

using (var context = new YOURContext())
{
    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) //--Startind transactions
    {
        try
        {
            context.YourObject1.Add(new YourObject1 { Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnet" });
            context.SaveChanges();

            context.YourObject2.Add(new YourObject2 { Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio" });
            context.SaveChanges();

            // Commit transaction if all commands succeed, transaction will auto-rollback
            // when disposed if either commands fails
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // TODO: Handle failure
        }
    }
}
```

Take care with updates, first recovery object and update after.

```
//--INSIDE YOU UPDATE METHOD--
...
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var dataYourObj1 = await _context.YourObj1.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == YourObj1.Id);

                        dataYourObj1.Name = obj1.Name;
                        dataYourObj1.Email = obj1.Email;
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                        var dataYourObj2 = await _context.YourObj2.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == dataYourObj2.Id);
                        dataYourObj2.field = obj2.Field;
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        Console.WriteLine("Error occurred." + ex);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

> By default, if the database provider supports transactions, all changes in a single call to SaveChanges are applied in a transaction. If any of the changes fail, then the transaction is rolled back and none of the changes are applied to the database. This means that SaveChanges is guaranteed to either completely succeed, or leave the database unmodified if an error occurs.
> For most applications, this default behavior is sufficient. You should only manually control transactions if your application requirements deem it necessary.

For example:

`var user = new User { Email = "email", UserName = "username" };                        dbContext.Users.Add(user);                                                             dbContext.Users.Add(new UserRole { RoleId = 1, UserId = user.id });                    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();`

For more information see below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions